# Creating polygons with different heights in Qgis2threejs

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis2threejs

i'm trying to display a polygon in qgis-2threejs which works fine. Now i want to adjust the height on the sides of the polygon, so that i can vary the body of the polygon.

Basically i want to display different fractures inside of a mountain with the height of each polygon adjusted to the surface.

See here:

[image]

Comment: Can't be done with polygons. It is 2.5D rather than 3D. Would have to be done as a raster DEM.

Comment: ok, i see. but can i connect the DEM, which i assume to be just displaying the surface, to the bottom? So that it looks kinda like a polygon...?

Comment: The image on the right was made with QGIS2ThreeJS: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-pGzk4Dt5hlc/Uz8vpq9H2QI/AAAAAAAAAfw/ZpAST0DBTpw/s1600/GoogleEarthandPluginResult.png

Comment: Ok, so i did the modelling with DEM´s and it worked like intended! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, it is not possible to get a sloped polygon in Qgis2treeJS.

However, you can create a second DEM with your mountain and display your lines on that surface.

You can then use your lines layer in Qgis2threeJS and select "profile" as object type. Then use the parameters Zcoordinate (mode absolute value, I'd recommend 0 ) and Height (the altitude of your layer) to draw a surface all the way through your model.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set height according to your column and multiplier that column with your  criteria. I did it with following way you can see screen shot of my process . this might help you   [image]

Comment: I don´t want to change the height of the polygon, i want to change the heights of the corner-points in the polygon, so that i get a polygon with a slope...